# Rolify undefined method `add_role' for #<User:0x00000109c39880> in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rolify

Just trying to install Rolify to make an admin role which has permissions to edit some concrete attributes...

I followed it's documentation step by step, everything looks fine except when I try to add a role to a user, it will say

`undefined method add_role for <User:0x00000109c39880>`

In my User model, I have the `rolify` method which should give the `add_role` method...

2 IMPORTANT NOTES:

Im using friendly_id
Im using devise gem

Anyone can help?

### User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  attr_accessor :tos_agreement
  is_impressionable :counter_cache => true, :column_name => :impressions_counter, :unique => :request_hash
  has_many :photos
  has_many :tags, through: :photos
  has_many :comments, through: :photos
  validates :tos_agreement, acceptance: true
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :omniauthable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  def update_with_password(params={}) 
    if params[:password].blank? 
      params.delete(:password) 
      params.delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:password_confirmation].blank? 
    end 
    update_attributes(params) 
  end

  # Omniauth Devise
  def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
    user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
    @user = user
    if user
      return user
    else
      registered_user = User.where(:email => auth.info.email).first
      if registered_user
        return registered_user
      else
        user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
          provider:auth.provider,
          uid:auth.uid,
          email:auth.info.email,
          password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20],
          )
        # if user.save
        #   UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
        # end
      end

    end
  end

end
```

#### Role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :users_roles
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true

  scopify
end
```

Thanks

Comment: Paste the code for the model.

Comment: Do you have `rolify` in your `User` model ?

Comment: Yes I do, please se update @ForgetTheNorm

Comment: @JorgedelosSantos posted, please help! Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you've restarted your Rails server? I've made the mistake so many times, forgetting that new gem installations cannot be automatically loaded.

Comment: Wow, restarting the server + the console worked. :/ Thanks @XA21X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restart your server :)

From my personal experiences, whenever I encounter a method which should exist and does not exist, I suspect that the method which is responsible for defining the method is not being called. I would have expected `rolify` to generate some exception instead of failing silently.

Rails development server will only reload your classes (what is specified in `config.autoload_paths`) automatically, libraries from gems will require a server restart. There are existing [tools](https://github.com/teohm/require_reloader) to auto reload gems.